# Making a timer in Python

Tags: python-3.x

What I want to do, is for example:

Print something like, "Welcome to my program"
Then create a timer for x seconds, after x seconds have passed, it does then next thing, like prints something else like, "To start type Hello"

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried]
(http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also 
help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

The [time](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) library is very useful:

```
>>> import time
>>> print "hello"
hello
>>> time.sleep(5)
# 5 second pause
>>> print "done"
done
```

That will pause all execution of the program for 5 seconds, during time.sleep(). If you want to do other things during the pause, it becomes a much more complicated question, and you should probably look into [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)